# Delete PFFile on Parse-server, the actual file system is filling up (long term plan switch to S3)

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-s3, parse-server, pffile

I am new to AWS and parse-server and I am using the parse-server bitami config from AWS marketplace.  I did a lot of dev testing and started getting an error that just said "can not store file".  After internet research and some help on SO I concluded it was because when I deleted the rows with PFFiles from the parse tables the actual files probably weren't getting deleted.

Where can I go to see what my storage limit is on AWS and see how I am to filling it up?

Is there function or a command that will remove all these orphan files so that I can confirm I am again under the limit?  Maybe this can be done on command line by logging on to the parse-server's ubuntu or perhaps by using the Parse-server internet based control panel? Right now I fixed this by just deleting my parse server instance and starting an entirely new one, but that meant I lost the rows I hadn't deleted as well.

When I launch on the app store I am going to switch to s3 for the PFFile to store the actual data storage so if you happen to know a good tutorial for that it would be much appreciated and a great addition to stackoverflow since I couldn't find anyone who previously answered that "how to"

Answer (score 0):

Found someone who knew the answer.  The PFFile doesn't actual store the file in parse-server and doesn't just save the bits and bytes on some random unix file path.  The files are in the mongoDB. To delete the actual file you have to delete it by logging on to the actual mongodb and removing it from the collection "fs.chunks" and "fs.files"

```
show collections
_Role
_SCHEMA
_Session
_User
fs.chunks
fs.files
```